# PHP, SOAP Response Error

Tags: php, curl, soap, wsdl

I am requesting the WSDL URL using PHP SOAP method but I am facing the below error.
**Error Getting Appserver DetailsCould not find AppServer/Companytrue**

```
$wsdl = "http://feeds.trinium4fuel.com/wsa/wsa1/wsdl?targetURI=urn:tempuri-org";

$options = array(
   'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
   'trace' => 1,
   'exceptions' => true,
   'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
   'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
   'soapaction' => ''
);

$params = array(
   'Company' => 'EmpireCFS',
   'Ascname' => 'AS-ECFS-WSV-LIVE',
   'User' => 'ECFS',
   'Password' => 'ECFS-PASS',
   'Programname' => 'p-ws-procedures.p',
   'Procname' => 'ip-get-fak-available',
   'Housebl' => '776655',
   'Itno' => '',
   'Piece' => '797',
   'Weight' => ''
```

);

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
$res = $soapClient->wstrinium($params);
var_dump($res);
```

Same request I have generated using SOAPUI and you can see the response.

[image]

How I can debug my code and parameters and get response in my code. Thanks

Comment: what is the output in php, can you give the results of var_dump?

Answer (score 0):

Your params array has to be within an array when you make the request, try this:

```
$res = $soapClient->wstrinium(array($params));
```